# ¿Cómo importar Jquery en AMP PWA?

Tags: jquery, pwa, amp

¿Cómo se debe hacer para usar JQuery en una aplicación Web que está en AMP y funciona como PWA, es decir tiene un service worker y un manifest.json?

Comment: Tienes algún problema de importarlo como cualquier otra librería JS?

Comment: @Vlady como estoy iniciando en AMP y PWA no he inyectado ninguna librería, en caso de que jquery se importe de la misma manera que cualquier otra librería, cuál sería esa forma? tomando en cuenta que la App está en AMP?

Comment: De la misma forma que se importa una librería en HTML `<script src="ruta_a_tu_jquery"></script>`